# Scrollbar doesn't show on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, scrollbar, dropdown

I have a list that is styled as dropdown menu.

I want the scrollbar to show so that user will know it is scrollable.
Scrollbar only shows when you scroll. I want it to show on default.

**NOTE: This works on desktop but not on a mobile device.**

Here are screenshots:

[Scroll bar doesnt show on default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5vxX.jpg)

[Scroll bar shows only when scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDafg.jpg)

Here is my code:

```css
.part-finder-container ul.floatleft 
{
  padding:0;
}

li.part-finder-vehicleyear
{
      border: 1px #f1f1f1 solid;
   padding: 18px 15px 16px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
}

.part-finder-dropdownlist ul
{
      max-height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
}

.vehicleyear li
{
      list-style-type: none;
   padding: 19px 0;
   border-top: 1px #f1f1f1 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="part-finder-container">
  <ul class="floatleft">
    <li class="part-finder-vehicleyear part-finder-vehicleenabled">
      <em>Select Year</em>
      <span class="arrow-down icon-arrow_drop_down"></span>
        <div class="part-finder-dropdownlist part-finder-dropdownlist-vehicleyear">
          <ul class="vehicleyear">
            <li>2014</li>
            <li>2013</li>
            <li>2012</li>
            <li>2011</li>
            <li>2010</li>
            <li>2009</li>
            <li>2008</li>
            <li>2007</li>
            <li>2006</li>
            <li>2005</li>
            <li>2004</li>
            <li>2003</li>
            <li>2002</li>
            <li>2001</li>
            <li>2000</li>
            <li>1999</li>
            <li>1998</li>
            <li>1997</li>
            <li>1996</li>
            <li>1995</li>
            <li>1994</li>
            <li>1993</li>
            <li>1992</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how all smartphone scrollbars work. Since space is at a premium on smartphones, the scrollbars stay hidden until they're needed.

Comment: @SteveVentimiglia Opps, thanks for the heads up. I have updated screenshots.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb That's what I was thinking. But I saw the dropdown on this website: https://www.carid.com/ and on mobile, it shows the scrollbar.

Comment: @Mei - Have you resolved this issue?  If not, go ahead and check out my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42101413/4298604).  Understand that scrollbar control has been an ongoing issue with IE and Firefox for quite some time, but that CSS is a nice fix for most mobile browsers.  

Otherwise, you can always go the JS route for a 100% solution, but I'm not a fan of creating solutions for core issues like this when it should be forced upon and addressed by the company responsible for causing them... not us.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so - at first - I thought it was being hidden by the parent element.  But it wasn't.  That's not the case on mobile devices (but a great method to hide it altogether on a long hamburger sidebar that shows content being cut off in landscape but still needs to scroll without wasting valuable space.)

In this case, you are actually hiding the scrollbar, in theory:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

However, when you add the following code afterwards to control the style of your scrollbar, it will immediately bring it back to the party - making it like half my friends... starving for attention.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
   width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
   height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: #ccc;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px solid #eee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
   background-color: #eee; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mess around with the scrollbar using the `-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo element:

```
-webkit-scrollbar,
-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  display: block !important;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think that you'd notice this issue in google chrome in macOS too. It's a design thing where sometimes the scrollbar is simply hidden and unless you write your own scrollbar code (a lot of work) than you just have to deal with it.

Comment: Can you please give me an idea on how to create own scrollbar code? I've been searching these past few days and all I can find is the ::-webkit-scrollbar CSS pseudo-element, which doesn't work on mobile as well.

Comment: I would not recommend that.  It would be like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I thought the element that I had the scrollbar on wasn't scrolling on a mobile device because the scroll grabber doesn't show up unless you touch the scrollable area. On a desktop browser the grabber always shows up. It must be a real estate thing on the mobile devices.

Here in the CSS in an Angular app that makes mine work on both desktop browser and mobile browser:

```
.message-text {  
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 20vw;
    margin-bottom:0px;  
    margin-top:5px;  
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-behavior: auto;
    /* scrollbar-color takes 2 colors. 1st is scroll grabber, 2nd background */
    scrollbar-color: rgb(23, 38, 182) rgb(162, 170, 238) ;
    scrollbar-width: auto;
}
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">  
    <p class="confirm-message">{{message.text}}</p>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Note: the inner div is sized in respect to the outer div, {{message.text}} is some short or very long text coming from the component.